# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') when adding functionality to modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to toggle a class list on and off so that when the button is clicked, the opacity of the modal is changed to 1 and when the close button is clicked, the class list is toggled off.

In the console, I see the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

I checked to make sure I had no typos and I don't see any. I can't figure out why there is an error.

HTML (index.html)

```
<button class="rulesButton">RULES</button>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modalContainer">
      <header class="modalHeader">
        <h2 class="modalHeading">RULES</h2>
        <button class="closeButton">
          <img src="/images/icon-close.svg" alt="Close button">
        </button>
      </header>
      <img src="/images/image-rules.svg" alt="Rules image" class="rulesImage">
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS (styles.css)

```
.rulesButton {
    background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 0.8rem;
    bottom: 2rem;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
    right: 2rem;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0.6rem 2.4rem;
    position: absolute;
}

.modal {
    background: #0000004d;
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    place-items: center;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
}

.modalContainer {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
}

.modalHeader {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.modalHeading {
    color: hsl(229, 25%, 31%);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.closeButton {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

.rulesImage {
    padding: 2rem 4rem;
}

.showModal { /* toggles on and off */
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: initial;
}
```

JavaScript (index.js)

```
const buttonRules = document.querySelector(".rulesButton");
const buttonClose = document.querySelector(".closeButton");
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");

//Toggle Modal 
buttonRules.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modal.classList.toggle("showModal");
});

buttonClose.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modal.classList.toggle("showModal");
});
```

Comment: Well have you tried console logging your buttonRules and buttonClose variables and seeing what you get

Comment: i did and it says null but i don't understand what that means @ZachJensz

Comment: Is this all of your markup? Do you have multiple elements with these same classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your script tag located in your HTML document? If it's in the `<head>` then the JavaScript will begin running before the browser has parsed the rest of the document. This means the button won't exist yet and therefore be `null`.

If this is the case, you can fix it by adding the script tag after the elements being queried in the HTML document.

Example:

JavaScript

```js
const testDiv = document.querySelector(".test");
console.log(testDiv.addEventListener);
```

HTML Script Before

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="select.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="test">Hello world</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

produces null returned from `document.querySelector`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') at select.js:3:21
```

HTML Script After

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="test">Hello world</div>
    <script src="select.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

produces a defined function

```
ƒ addEventListener() { [native code] }
```

Comment: You're likely right in your assumption

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to move the whole script tag down, just add 'defer' to the script tag so it waits for the whole doc to load before executing.

Comment: Please show with some code example.

Comment: Just add defer to the script tag and it wouldn't load the script until the page has loaded